# Running tests with color using vim-vroom plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, vim

I'm using minitest with Rails 4 and vim as my main code editor. To display colors (red or green) when I run my tests I use [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) gem and it works as I expected.

The problem is when I try to run my tests inside vim with [vim-vrooom](https://github.com/skalnik/vim-vroom) plugin. They run well but colors are not displayed. Is there any configuration I can set to format test output?

Comment: Are you talking Bout vim background colors?

Comment: Try `:h vroom_use_colors`

Comment: I'm talking about passed (green) and failures (red) tests. vroom_use_colors is already enabled.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.